# How to replace or display the special characters from JSON API plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-json-api, web-services

[image]I started using the JSON API plugin. It works good ! But the problem i am facing is, If i enter any text containing special characters through CMS The output is not same as the given text. Why this is happening?

Example: It's a good app (Input)
         The output looks like It ' s a good app.
Please suggest any tips/methods to get rid of this situation.

Eagerly waiting for your response.
Thank you

Comment: What is the difference between "It's a good app" (input) and "It's a good app" (output)? I see none.

Comment: Please check , I have edited my question as shown in image. but stackoverflow displayed special character '. And this(stackoverflow scenario ) is what i want.

Comment: Some degree encoding is always required. Otherwise how would you, for example, send JSON string (as part of post or something) in JSON? It would break horribly without encoding special characters. This is matter of properly decoding JSON data in your client application, not a problem with data output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because the "JSON API plugin" htmlescapes your text. So if you would just display it on site it should print OK, but if you need to work with it on the backend than just use `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: I am not displaying data on my site. I want the webservice to be used by an ios developer. Any settings to be made in this plugin so that i can modify accordingly. Ya i am familiar with  html_entity_decode() when coding in php. As it is a word press site how can i implement. I am new to wordpress custom coding.

Comment: Then your iOS developer has to solve this. Have him look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape